# Purposes of two-sided/one-sided specific while testing independence with Fisher's exact test, Chi-square test

Tags: statistics, categorical-data, chi-squared, hypothesis-test, statistical-test

I'm struggling to understand the operation behind Fisher's exact test & Chi-squared test. As I understand, both of the tests do the same thing that is to test for the independence between 2 categorical data.
For example, I have the contingency table as below:

```
              Men         Women     
Studying       1            9        
Not-studying  11            3
```

Then using the Fisher's test would tell me whether the proportion of studying individuals is the same for both genders or not (i.e. whether the proportion of studying is independent of gender or not). Is that correct?
If yes, then why do we need to specify whether it should be a two-sided test or one-sided test for a Fisher's test/Chi-square? As I don't see testing for independence has anything to do with a two-sided or one-sided test?
Am I missing something or do we actually need to specify whether it's a two-sided or a one-sided when computing a Fisher/Chi-square?

Comment: A better place to post this question might be [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).  In any event as a start towards understanding, either here or there, maybe edit the question to include "expected values" corresponding to these data (what the ideal data would be if the null hypothesis is true), and two opposite sets of hypothetical extreme data that could occur if the null hypothesis is not true.  Also this is duplicate of [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/325744).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Chi square test can be used to test independence (in your case proportion of studying is independent of gender or not). You don't need to worry about whether it's a two-sided or a one-sided. Let me elaborate

**Observed Table**:

|  | **Men** | **Women** | **Total** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Studying** | 1 | 9 | 10 |
| **Not-studying** | 11 | 3 | 14 |
| **Total** | 12 | 12 | 24 |

H0 : Proportion of students studying is independent of gender

H1 : proportion of students studying is dependent of gender

For variables to be independent i.e. for gender and studying proportion to be independent the above table should look something like this

**Expected Table** for independence:

|  | **Men** | **Women** | **Total** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Studying** | 5 | 5 | 10 |
| **Not-studying** | 7 | 7 | 14 |
| **Total** | 12 | 12 | 24 |

As its independent of gender, its distributed equally

now chi square factor is measured as below:

```
 Summation over all the cells (observed - expected)^2/expected
```

thats 10.97 in this case

**High Chi square values:**
Higher Chi square values mean, large difference between observed and expected values, large difference signifies that the observed sequence is not as expected for independence, we can reject Null hypothesis

**Low Chi square value:**
Low chi square values mean, small difference between observed and expected values, i.e. observed values are as expected for condition of independence, We can accept Null hypothesis

In short, Higher Chi square values reject Null hypothesis and small Chi square values accept Null hypothesis. This means that chi square is always a one tailed test with rejection region on the right.

We don't need to specify whether it's a two-sided or a one-sided when computing a Fisher/Chi-square.